# Certain cookies are blocked cross domain when using an ajax request

Tags: ajax, authentication, cookies, request, header

I'm using a react app running on localhost:3000 which makes ajax requests to our website. We recently switched our authentification system from using WordPress authentification to https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth.

Since then, using the same settings inside ajax and on our web server, our authentification cookies are not sent cross domain. However, it's working when requesting them from the same domain.

Our request:

```
fetchLoginStatus = () => {
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.withCredentials = true;
    ajax.open("POST", "https://our-website.com/src/php/checkLoggedIn.php");
    ajax.onload = () => {
      const response = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
    };
    ajax.send();   
};
```

Our request headers (from localhost:3000):

```
:authority: my-website.com
:method: POST
:path: /src/php/checkLoggedIn.php
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-length: 0
cookie: plesk-items-per-page; plesk-sort-field, phpMyAdmin; databases-active-list-state-collapsed; plesk-list-type; io=R_dL3fjUEYe64ykHAAAp; isAsyncProgressBarCollapsed=true; PLESKSESSID; plesk-sort-dir;
origin: https://localhost:3000
referer: https://localhost:3000/
```

Our response headers (we are running an nginx server):

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type 
access-control-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS access-` 
control-allow-origin: https://localhost:3000 
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate 
content-encoding: br  
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
date: Sun, 10 Mar 2019 15:26:08 GMT 
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT pragma: 
no-cache server: nginx 
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=someId; 
path=/; SameSite=Lax status: 200 
vary: Accept-Encoding 
x-powered-by: PleskLin`
```

When I don't send the request cross-domain PHPSESSID is inside the cookies of my request headers. However when I send the request from localhost:3000 it's not there.

Does somebody know how I can send the PHPSESSID from localhost too?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the same question inside the github repository and the owner solved it.

https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth/issues/154

Solution:

vendor/delight-im/auth/src/UserManager.php

```
Replace Session::regenerate(true); with Session::regenerate(true, null);
```

vendor/delight-im/auth/src/Auth.php

```
Replace @Session::start(); with @Session::start(null);
Replace Session::regenerate(true); with Session::regenerate(true, null);
After $cookie->setSecureOnly($params['secure']); append $cookie- 
>setSameSiteRestriction(null); in all three (!) occurrences
```